# How to call to a list of established objects? (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, object, null

I have this code (and excuse the language) that my friend made for a game we are working on. The code is meant to create a list of possible weapons to pick up throughout the game, however it always returns a null value. So I made a method arms.printAllGuns(), which printed ever gun and then "null" at the very bottom without giving my a null point error(since it was only returning the name). So it seems to successfully establish every object as intended, but it creates an extra null Gun object, and can't properly return any object in the array.

This is giving the null

```
import java.util.*;
public class Soldier
{
    //BASE
    private ArrayList <Gun> gunsCarried;
    private GunsAvalible arms = new GunsAvalible();
    private Armor armor;
    private int size;
    private int bodyTempature;//1-10
    private int health = 100;
    private int numberOfSpecials;


public Soldier(int s, int g)
{
    Gun temp = arms.get(g);
    temp.getGunName();
    final int size = s;
}

public void takeDamage(int damage)
{
    health -= damage; 
}
}
```

And then here is the List of guns

```
public class GunsAvalible
{
    Gun [] gunsArray = new Gun [40];
    public GunsAvalible()
    {
        //(Name, ClipSize, Power)
        gunsArray[0] = new Gun("Hucker", 13, 10);//PISTOL
        gunsArray[1] = new Gun("Rafile", 10, 15);//RIFLE
        gunsArray[2] = new Gun("Slumper", 14, 14);//PISTOL
        gunsArray[3] = new Gun("Normality", 3, 40);//SHOTGUN
        gunsArray[4] = new Gun("Feminest Friendly", 1, 1);//TAZER
        gunsArray[5] = new Gun("China Man", 32, 5);//MACHINEGUN
        gunsArray[6] = new Gun("Bax", 6, 25);//SNIPER
        gunsArray[7] = new Gun("Regicidal Tyranus", 7, 20);//SPECIAL
        gunsArray[8] = new Gun("Blaking", 12, 15);//RIFLE
        gunsArray[9] = new Gun("Olive Branch", 4, 50);//SNIPER
        gunsArray[10] = new Gun("DYL-SCHO", 0,0);//SNIPER
        gunsArray[11] = new Gun("Forrest Burrner",0,0 );//FLAMETHROWER
        gunsArray[12] = new Gun("Sahaka",0,0);//Hose
        gunsArray[13] = new Gun("Chirper", 16, 7);//PISTOL
        gunsArray[14] = new Gun("Gourd", 1, 100);
        gunsArray[15] = new Gun("Fohell", 0, 0);
        gunsArray[16] = new Gun("Candle Stick", 0, 0);
        gunsArray[17] = new Gun("Rock Wing",0 ,0);
        gunsArray[18] = new Gun("Busting Pain", 0 ,0);
        gunsArray[19] = new Gun("Wosham's Anahe",0,0);
        gunsArray[20] = new Gun("Fucker", 13, 10);//PISTOL
        gunsArray[21] = new Gun("Rafiphile", 10, 15);//RIFLE
        gunsArray[22] = new Gun("Humper", 14, 14);//PISTOL
        gunsArray[23] = new Gun("Reality", 3, 40);//SHOTGUN
        gunsArray[24] = new Gun("Dick Frier", 1, 1);//TAZER
        gunsArray[25] = new Gun("Yellow River", 32, 5);//MACHINEGUN
        gunsArray[26] = new Gun("Bax-Stabber", 6, 25);//SNIPER
        gunsArray[27] = new Gun("Regicidal Tyranus II", 7, 20);//SPECIAL
        gunsArray[28] = new Gun("Faking", 12, 15);//RIFLE
        gunsArray[29] = new Gun("Broken Branch", 4, 50);//SNIPER
        gunsArray[30] = new Gun("DYL-DO", 0,0);//SNIPER
        gunsArray[31] = new Gun("Worrld Burrner",0,0 );//FLAMETHROWER
        gunsArray[32] = new Gun("Water Will",0,0);//Hose
        gunsArray[33] = new Gun("Chirper", 16, 7);//PISTOL
        gunsArray[34] = new Gun("Budai", 1, 100);//RPG
        gunsArray[35] = new Gun("Fovaehan",0,0);
        gunsArray[36] = new Gun("Candle Stick",0,0);
        gunsArray[37] = new Gun("Rock Wing",0,0);
        gunsArray[38] = new Gun("Riding Vain",0,0);
        gunsArray[39] = new Gun("IF-EA",0,0);
    }


    public Gun get(int gunNumber)
    {
        return gunsArray[gunNumber];
    }


}
```

and lastly the gun class

```
public class Gun
{
    private String name = ("");
    private int ammo = 0;
    private int clipSize = 0;
    private int clip = 0;
    private int power = 0;

    private Gun [] gunsArray = new Gun [20];
    private Gun [] gunsRankIIArray = new Gun [20];
    public Gun(String n, int cs, int p)
    {
        final int clipSize = cs;
    clip = 1 + (int)(3.14 *  5 * Math.random());
    power = p;
    name = n;
    if(clip > clipSize)
        clip = clipSize;
}

public void ammoPickup(int a)
{
    ammo += a;
}

public int fire()
{
    if(clip == 0)
    {
        reload();
        return 0;
    }
    clip--;
    int damage = 0;
    double critical = Math.random();
    if(critical < .5)
    {
        damage = (int)(power * (1+critical));
    }
    else 
    {
        damage = power * 2;
    }
    return damage;
}

public boolean reload()
{
    if(ammo > 0)
    {
        ammo -= clipSize;
        clip += clipSize;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public String getGunName()
{
    return name;
}
}
```

I appreciate any help or tips, because I'm sorta at a stand still

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing

```
gunsCarried = new ArrayList<>();
gunsCarried.add(temp);
```

in your Soldier constructor.

Comment: i removed it for right now because it kept giving me the null point error, thanks though